# Tinyproxy installation issue in OS X

Tags: macos

I am trying to install Tinyproxy in my Yosemite OS X. But after installation when I type `tinyproxy` in the command line, it shows

> tinyproxy command not found.

I followed [Using Tinyproxy for Mobile Development on OS X](http://davidalger.com/development/using-tinyproxy-for-mobile-development-on-os-x/).

Please refer the command line commands below.

```
TOD-BLR-C02L479RFFRP:~ pradeepachuthan$ brew install tinyproxy
==> Downloading https://www.banu.com/pub/tinyproxy/1.8/tinyproxy-1.8.3.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tinyproxy-1.8.3.tar.bz2
==> Downloading https://trac.macports.org/export/83413/trunk/dports/net/tinyproxy/files/patch-configure.diff
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tinyproxy--patch-e946269b681f3ffaa1acd120c93050cb63bfe743.diff
==> Patching
patching file configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 6744 (offset -1 lines).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/tinyproxy/1.8.3 --disable-regexcheck
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/tinyproxy/1.8.3: 14 files, 244K, built in 6.4 minutes
TOD-BLR-C02L479RFFRP:~ pradeepachuthan$ tinyproxy
-bash: tinyproxy: command not found
TOD-BLR-C02L479RFFRP:~ pradeepachuthan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ which tinyproxy
/usr/local/sbin/tinyproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it's not reaching the executable, do `brew info tinyproxy` to find out